# Excel equivalent of arrays using in Python pandas

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas

I have a large pandas *dataframe* as below. Need to add two more columns with sales max and min values of the particular brand.

```
 date      brand   price    quantity      sales   vat
31-May-13   Reebok      10      23          230     3.5
31-May-13   Adidas      10      25          250     2.8
31-May-13   Campus      8       21          168     3.5
31-May-13   Nike        10      20          200     6.5
31-May-13   Woods       2       7           14      2.8
01-Jun-13   Reebok      4       27          108     2.2
01-Jun-13   Adidas      7       28          196     3.8
01-Jun-13   Campus      7       41          287     4.2
01-Jun-13   Nike        2       39          78      7.2
01-Jun-13   Woods       5       26          130     3.3
02-Jun-13   Reebok      10      5           50      2.2
02-Jun-13   Adidas      10      15          150     3.8    
02-Jun-13   Woods       6       30          180     3.3
```

Here my date column is not in order, and all brand data is not available for evey date in the date column. And the result should look like,

```
 date      brand   price    quantity      sales     vat    Max    Min   
31-May-13   Reebok      10      23          230     3.5    230    50
31-May-13   Adidas      10      25          250     2.8    250    150
31-May-13   Campus      8       21          168     3.5    287    168
31-May-13   Nike        10      20          200     6.5    200    78
31-May-13   Woods       2       7           14      2.8    180    14 
01-Jun-13   Reebok      4       27          108     2.2    230    50
01-Jun-13   Adidas      7       28          196     3.8    250    150
01-Jun-13   Campus      7       41          287     4.2    287    168
01-Jun-13   Nike        2       39          78      7.2    200    78
01-Jun-13   Woods       5       26          130     3.3    180    14 
02-Jun-13   Reebok      10      5           50      2.2    230    50
02-Jun-13   Adidas      10      15          150     3.8    250    150  
02-Jun-13   Woods       6       30          180     3.3    180    14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use groupby.transform:

```
df['max'] = df.groupby('brand')['sales'].transform('max')
df['min'] = df.groupby('brand')['sales'].transform('min')

df
Out: 
         date   brand  price  quantity  sales  vat  max  min
0  2013-05-31  Reebok     10        23    230  3.5  230   50
1  2013-05-31  Adidas     10        25    250  2.8  250  150
2  2013-05-31  Campus      8        21    168  3.5  287  168
3  2013-05-31    Nike     10        20    200  6.5  200   78
4  2013-05-31   Woods      2         7     14  2.8  180   14
5  2013-06-01  Reebok      4        27    108  2.2  230   50
6  2013-06-01  Adidas      7        28    196  3.8  250  150
7  2013-06-01  Campus      7        41    287  4.2  287  168
8  2013-06-01    Nike      2        39     78  7.2  200   78
9  2013-06-01   Woods      5        26    130  3.3  180   14
10 2013-06-02  Reebok     10         5     50  2.2  230   50
11 2013-06-02  Adidas     10        15    150  3.8  250  150
12 2013-06-02   Woods      6        30    180  3.3  180   14
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupby and then join with original dataframe:

```
>>> g = df.groupby('brand')['sales'].agg([np.min, np.max])
>>> g
        amin  amax
brand             
Adidas   150   250
Campus   168   287
Nike      78   200
Reebok    50   230
Woods     14   180
>>> df.join(g, on='brand')
         date   brand  price  quantity  sales  vat  amin  amax
0   31-May-13  Reebok     10        23    230  3.5    50   230
1   31-May-13  Adidas     10        25    250  2.8   150   250
2   31-May-13  Campus      8        21    168  3.5   168   287
3   31-May-13    Nike     10        20    200  6.5    78   200
4   31-May-13   Woods      2         7     14  2.8    14   180
5   01-Jun-13  Reebok      4        27    108  2.2    50   230
6   01-Jun-13  Adidas      7        28    196  3.8   150   250
7   01-Jun-13  Campus      7        41    287  4.2   168   287
8   01-Jun-13    Nike      2        39     78  7.2    78   200
9   01-Jun-13   Woods      5        26    130  3.3    14   180
10  02-Jun-13  Reebok     10         5     50  2.2    50   230
11  02-Jun-13  Adidas     10        15    150  3.8   150   250
12  02-Jun-13   Woods      6        30    180  3.3    14   180
```